# How to efficiently export 3 million documents from MongoDB Atlas collection to CSV file using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, csv, export-to-csv

we have a collection in MongoDB Atlas with 3 million documents and using NodeJS we need to export them to CSV. We cannot use MONGOEXPORT or MONGODUMP, it is a process that must be developed as an API.

For this, we are working with the fast-csv library, but we have the problem that we must pass an array to the fastcsv.write() method as input data for the creation of the CSV.

The problem is that the transformation to an array of the 3 million documents returned by the query to Mongo is consuming a lot of time and memory.

Could you give us a hand to know how to develop this for it works in the most efficient way possible?

Here is a sample of the code we are testing.

[image]

P.D.
Questions that can also help us:

1. Do you know of any library or way to do this more efficiently?
2. Is there a way to NOT have to convert the data returned in the query to an array so that it is written to the CSV file?

Thank you.

````
    const aggCursor = colInventarioInstalaciones.aggregate(pipeline, pipelineOptions)    
    .toArray((err, data) => { //<<===== taking a lot of time
        //console.log("se ejecuta punto 3 del metodo");
        if (err) 
        throw err;

        const ws = fs.createWriteStream("pruebaTC1.csv");
        fastcsv.write(data, { headers: true })  //<<===== need to be array for write data in the file
        .on("finish", function() {
            var datetime = new Date();
            console.log(datetime);
            console.log("Write to pruebaTC1.csv successfully!");
        }).pipe(ws);

    });```
````

Comment: Sorry guys I forget to say Hi.

Comment: I think a pre-generated csv file is a better solution than just in time.

Comment: Do you know the column headers of the csv beforehand or will we need to dynamically add columns as we get some new keynames in the documents fetched from db?

Comment: Hi @YuTing, sorry but I don't get it. What do you mean with pre-generated? What we are trying to do is query the database for data that changes from month to month and then generate the CSV. Pre-generated how would it work? Thanks

Comment: Hi @AnujPancholi, we need add dynamically the columns name from the data of the query. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally would NEVER recommend using `.toArray()` to query an indefinite/very large no. of documents, as you're asking nodejs to fetch 3milllion documents from your db and store the whole thing in one humongosaurus array in memory. Hope you have a high-spec computer. Also, it won't write anything to a file unless the whole thing is in memory, if that ever happens.

Instead, I would be iterating the cursor so that at any given point I only have 1 doc in memory and I pipe that to the writestream.

Since you are reading 3 million documents, it is going to take time, it's just a matter of how much. At least with this approach, you're going to be writing the documents in the csv file as they're being read, instead of writing the whole thing at once from memory.

I wrote a small script to iterate over the whole thing via `cursor.next()`, document-by-document, and tested it.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'supersecretmongourlhere';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'db_name_here';


const run = async() => {
    try{
        await client.connect();
        console.log("db connected");
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        console.time("X")

        const pipelineStages = [{
            $match: {
                // your pipeline here
            }
        },{
            $sort: {
                _id: -1
            }
        },{
            $limit: 50000
        }]

        const cursor = db.collection('collection_name_here').aggregate(pipelineStages)

        const csvStream = csv.format({ headers: true });

        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./myfile.csv');

        csvStream.pipe(writeStream).on('end',() => {
            console.log("DONE");
        }).on('error',err => console.error(err));

        while(await cursor.hasNext()){
            const doc = await cursor.next();
            csvStream.write(doc);
            console.log(`${doc._id} written`);
        }
        console.log('done')
        console.timeEnd("X")
        csvStream.end();
        writeStream.end();

    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    
}

run();
```

[image: output]

For 50000 documents, 1:17.987s = 77987ms, 50000/77987 = 1.56ms/document.
1.56*3000000 = 4680s = **~78mins**

Is that acceptable in your use case?

**Yes, I know this isn't a very fast solution** but it will work.

There might be some way to speed it up further by fetching docs in batches from the db, will look into it if I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anuj, we will analyze your solution and tell you how everything turned out.